# get checkbox value to javascript from SQL output

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I asked a question last week that turned out to be entirely my mistake in a section I assumed to be correct, but once the primary issue was resolved I am still left unable to get my line variable to my Javascript code. I have no actual experience with Javascript unfortunately and all tutorials or answered questions I find only show me how to get a specific checkbox to my Javascript, not one from a variable line.

Here is what I am trying to do, I have a report running with PHP from my SQL server database which reports every item without a sent date, this could be hundreds of items at a time, each line has some information about the unsent item and a checkbox, the checkbox has an "onclick" event to call my Javascript, which calls a PHP page and writes a sent date to the database for that item.

The current code works if I hard code an EID into my PHP link, so everything except passing a variable has been tested and works. Here is my code:

PHP

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>
   <td><a href='vieweid.php?EID=" . $row['EID'] . "'>view</a></td>
   <td><input type='checkbox' onclick='issent(this)' name='sent[$i]' value='" . $row['EID'] . "'/></td>
   </tr>";
   $i++;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function issent(cb){

    if($(cb).is(":checked"))
      {
      var jsEID = $(this).val()
      $.getScript("sentscript.php?EID="jsEID);
      }

    }
</script>
```

I'm not certain if the variable is not being filled in JS or if I'm calling it incorrectly as part of my $.getscript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*..The current code works if I hard code an EID into my PHP link,*". So problem is retrieving EID??

Comment: Use the Javascript `console.log(jsEID)` in combination with the F12 key in a browser (not IE!) to see if the ID is correclty filled in. Use `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>` in your php script to see if the ID reaches the PHP script.

Comment: Nana, yes the issue is in passing EID from the form to the Javascript, the remainder of the code works. Cagy it does not appear to see the variable and I get the below error:

jquery-latest.js:7722 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**

**1)** `var jsEID = $(this).val()`

to

`var jsEID = $(cb).val();`

**2)** `$.getScript("sentscript.php?EID="jsEID);`

to

`$.getScript("sentscript.php?EID="+jsEID);`

**Updated Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function issent(cb){
    if($(cb).is(":checked")){
      var jsEID = $(cb).val();
      $.getScript("sentscript.php?EID="+jsEID);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No change in behaviour with the above.

Comment: Please check my updated code. @SarahHartt. Now, it will work.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @SarahHartt : *Keep Coding*. Thanks.